# Faulty relay(s), capacitor or power source?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, relay, troubleshooting

I have this IKEA Bekant Sit/Stand electrical desk and all of the sudden today, it won't work properly. I push it to go up or down and it goes for a little bit and then stops. I can hear well the relays switching but I don't know if they are switching to ON and then place themselves on OFF. I disassembled the whole thing and I can say that all the mechanical parts involved work perfectly  (nothing is stuck) and then I have to conclude that is something electrical.
I have made a video so you can get an idea of what is happening.
Basically, I have  power source of 25V and 2.5Amps. When on "idle" the multimeter shows ~25V. When I press UP or DOWN on the desk controller the multimeter shows a drastic decrease and the voltage goes to ~2-3V (I have even seen it going to ~0V) and then when the relays switch back to OFF the voltage goes to ~35 and then slowly comes back to ~25.

[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/_yZVobetx2w)

Comment: Is that a decrease OF 2 - 3 volts, or a decrease TO 2 - 3 volts?  A decrease OF 2 - 3 volts may be OK, but a decrease TO 2 - 3 volts would indicate a power supply problem.  Does IKEA offer any warrantee on the thing?

Comment: Modified my post. The voltage goes TO ~0-3 volts when I try to raise or lower the desk! I am also out of the warranty!

Comment: I see two motors; are there more involved (sounds like it)? Can you try the system with one motor at a time?

Comment: Tried only one at a time and altough it did not stop, it was very sluggish. Connected both and got the same issue.

Comment: If you have some beefy resistor[s], you should test the power supply separately see if it holds the load it's supposed to. Not necessarily to 60W, but pehaps if you could test with something around 30W you'd get an idea if it can still supply that. If you have an old/broken space heater, you can use its nichrome wire to make a custom resistor of sufficient power. Otherwise you'd probably have to buy some (for this method.)

Comment: Also incandescent (with halogen or not) bulbs make good substitute loads. Make sure you calculate the current & power properly given that you won't be using them at their label voltage. Nichorome has the great advantage that it doesn't change its resistance with temperature (within a wide band), that's why it's used in heaters.

Comment: Also, you could buy (or try to improvise) another power supply to test the other way around. 24V ones aren't hard to find. Perhaps buy from a store with "no questions asked" return policy if you're feeling cheap... Or use two car/UPS batteries etc.

Comment: For what it's worth, I woke up this morning to my Bekant desk doing the exact same thing. I haven't taken it apart as I'm hoping to warranty-replace it, but the symptoms you describe (including the power supply LED going out) are the same.

Comment: I just had a short conversation with IKEA USA support on Twitter and they are sending a replacement power supply and wiring harness from Europe. Should be here in a week.

Comment: I got a replacement power supply as well and now everything works fine. The other power supply still works but not if I leave it plugged in for days (to make it work, you have to unplug it for 30 - 60 min and then after you plug it in it will work).

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct possibilities:

1) The power supply is defective and cannot supply the current required by the motors.

2) Something is consuming **way** too much current and the supply voltage is dropping as a result of that excessive current consumption.

My first step would be to measure the current coming out of the power supply and observe what happens when the relay(s) close.  Although you can use a multimeter to do this, you may get erroneous readings.

Here's why: if this is a switch-mode power supply with fold-back current limit and something is drawing excessive current, the power supply voltage will collapse to the point where the current consumption is below the damage level.  That may also involve having the current drop to a low (sometimes very low) level.  Your multimeter will show only that low level.

Better yet would be to use a low-value shunt resistor with a scope across the resistor.  Usually, you can insert the current shunt into the power supply (-) lead, which makes connecting the scope easy.

Comment: Already measured what happens. Check the youtube video!